# Retornando get_status_display no json (Django)

Tags: django

Eu criei uma Issue.

https://github.com/rg3915/orcamentos/issues/53

Eu fiz um gráfico usando Morris JS

https://github.com/rg3915/orcamentos/blob/master/img/graphic.png

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pergunta: como eu faço para retornar get_status_display no json?

```
import json
from django.db.models import Count
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Proposal


def proposal_per_status_json(request):
    ''' Quantidade de orçamentos por status '''
    data = Proposal.objects.values('status')\
        .annotate(value=Count('status'))\
        .order_by('status').values('status', 'value')
    '''
    Precisa reescrever o dicionário com os campos do gráfico,
    que são: 'label' e 'value'.
    '''
    data = [{'label': x['status'], 'value':x['value']} for x in data]
    s = json.dumps(list(data), cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
    return HttpResponse(s)
```

http://localhost:8000/proposal/proposal/proposal_per_status_json/

```
[{"label": "a", "value": 11}, {"label": "c", "value": 9}, {"label": "co", "value": 28}, {"label": "elab", "value": 9}, {"label": "p", "value": 14}]
```

Mas eu queria

```
[{"label": "aprovado", "value": 11}, {"label": "cancelado", "value": 9}, {"label": "concluído", "value": 28}, {"label": "em elaboração", "value": 9}, {"label": "pendente", "value": 14}]

STATUS_FILTER = (
    ('c', 'cancelado'),
    ('elab', 'em elaboração'),
    ('p', 'pendente'),
    ('co', 'concluido'),
    ('a', 'aprovado')
)
```

Comment: O que vc quer não é um JSON válido. JSONs são basicamente objetos em JavaScript, e o que vc postou são dois valores, uma lista e uma tupla. Você pode converter isso num dict, mas não é ideal incluir dados que se repetem em requisições AJAX por conta do overhead. Sugiro incluir os status na renderização do template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from orcamentos.utils.lists import STATUS_LIST
p=Proposal.objects.values('status')\
.annotate(value=Count('status'))\
.order_by('status').values('status', 'value')
lista=[]
for item in p:
    for choice in STATUS_LIST:
        if choice[0] == item['status']:
            lista.append({'label': choice[1], 'value': item['value']})

return lista
```

Comment: Outra solução um pouco mais performática `lista = [{'label': STATUS_DICT[item['status']], 'value': item['value']} for item in data]`.